# Change width of bootstrap input field

Tags: html

I have made an input form and one of the inputs is an amount, everything works however the field seems to take the width of my entire browser, anyone know why?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2.00" width="50px" name="amount"><br>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2.00" style="width:50px" name="amount"><br>
```

Use style ;)

Comment: This works, however it is no longer center aligned along with everything else in my <div class="row text-center"> Any ideas?

Comment: could you post a bit of the content within the <div class="row text-center"> div.

Comment: Ignore the above, I see what you mean. Gimme a sec

Comment: Nevermind, I have fixed the alignment issue by using '<div align="center">' instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the whole form a certain length (50%)
Use:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" style="width:50%;">
     //your form
  </form>
```

or:

```
 <div style="width:50%;">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
       //your form
    </form>
 </div>
```

or:

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2.00" width="50px" name="amount" style="width:50%;"><br>
```

I used the second option. [example](http://www.thewhateverclub.altervista.org/index.php?page=loginpage)